# How to create JSON format dictionary?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to format my data with a key to access the information. This is what I currently have:

```
    const dict = [];
    dict.push({"student": "Brian", "id":"01", "grade":"Sophomore"})
    return dict;
```

Output:

```
{
      "student":"Brian"
      "id": "01",
      "grade": "Sophomore"
}
```

However, I am interested in creating this type of format with my data:

```
{
  "student":"Brian" [ 

 { 
    "id":"01", 
    "grade": "Sophomore" 
 }

  ]
}
```

How would I be able to do so? I would like to use "student" as my key to access the rest of its information associated.

Comment: No, not in the way you have it here ... you would need an accessor name to the array containing the id and grade.  Also you proposed a VERY strange format.  I can see no reason that you would next the id in a single entry array.  You'd have to access that id value like obj['thingthatismissingtogettothearray][0]['id']

Comment: Your `dict` is an array, which is made for quick access to elements by numeric index. objects, which you've added to the array, are meant for quick access to elements by string index. So use an object. `{ student: { name: "Brian", id: "101", grade: "Sophomore" } }`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON in any case. JSON is a text format; once you bring things like `const` and `return` into it, your solidly in plain old JavaScript land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically there. However objects always need keys to go along with the values, so you need to assign a key to the object you want to create

```js
const dict = [];
dict.push({
  "Brian": {
    "id": "01",
    "grade": "Sophomore"
  }
})
// to retrieve: 
let brian = dict.filter(e=>Object.keys(e)[0]==="Brian").flatMap(Object.values)
if (brian && brian.length>0) console.log(brian[0])

//You could also set up your `dict` like this:

const dict2 = {};
dict2["Brian"] = {
  "id": "01",
  "grade": "Sophomore"
};

//and that would allow you to retrieve your object with

brian = dict2.Brian;
console.log(brian)
```

Comment: is there any way to just have it like "Brian" : {"id":"01", "grade":"Sophomore"}

Comment: Yes, revised my answer. Also if you want to store the student inside the object `dict.push({"Brian" : {"student": "Brian", "id":"01", "grade":"Sophomore"}})`

Comment: Revised my answer again with another way of approaching this, plus how to retrieve values. cheers